# Why does SymPy ignore my initial condition?

Tags: sympy, differential-equations

```
import sympy as sp

t = sp.Symbol("t")
y = sp.Function("y")
v = sp.Function("v")

sol = sp.dsolve([
        y(t).diff(t) - v(t),
        v(t).diff(t) + 2*y(t)
    ],
    ics={y(0):2, v(0):0.45})
sol
```

gives:

```
[y(t) == C1*sin(sqrt(2)*t) + C2*cos(sqrt(2)*t),
 v(t) == sqrt(2)*C1*cos(sqrt(2)*t) - sqrt(2)*C2*sin(sqrt(2)*t)]
```

Why are `C1` and `C2` not calculated?

Comment: It looks like it's a known issue: https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/issues/120 it shouldn't be too hard to patch this but I might be wrong. Edit: note that that's not the main repo, you might want to open an issue here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues